# Interchange the Y and Z axis in 3D- isosurface plot

Tags: matlab, interchange, rotor

The last few days I'm having trouble trying to interchange the Y- and Z- axis on a 3D- isosurface plot. I want to interchange the Y- and Z-axis in order to visualise it and to be able to discuss the result more clearly. I remember that in the past I used to interchange the Y- and Z-axis in two ways:

1) using the axis-handle:

```
    yy = get(gca, 'YData');
    zz = get(gca, 'Zdata');
    set(gca, 'YData', zz, 'ZData', yy);
```

The error I encounter is the following: 'There is no 'Ydata' property in the 'axes' class.'

2) interchanging by switching the data in the isosurface-command:

isosurface(X, Z, Y, calulated_rotor, iso_value)
I get the following error: 'X, Y and Z must be matrices produced by MESHGRID.'

However, X,Y,Z are generated using meshgrid. I tried to solve this error:

```
    [X Z Y] = meshgrid(x, z, y) % instead of [X Y Z] = meshgrid(x, z, y)  
    % recalculate the velocity matrices VX, VY, VZ: 3D-matrices , code not provided
    calculated_rotor_2 = rotor(X, Z, Y, VX, VZ, VY) % instead of calculated_rotor = rotor(X,Y,Z, VX, VY, VZ)
    isosurface(X, Z, Y, calculated_rotor_2, iso_value) % instead of isosurface(X, Y, Z, calculated_rotor, iso_value)
```

However this displays not the rotated version of the first rotor I calulated. It displays a wrong calculated rotor. So my main question remains: How can I interchange the Y and Z axis in a correct way?

My Matlab version is R2010a.

Answer (score 0):

The `'YData'` property belongs to the Surfaceplot, not the Axes, so that's why you get the error. The handle of that Surfaceplot is returned by `mesh()` call, for example (please check the doc of your plotting function). You could also query the `'Children'` property of your `gca` to obtain this handle (if `gca` really is the handle of the axis that holds the surface).

As for the `rotor` call... is it the Curl? If yes, you should be aware that changing the relative orientation of your reference frame (e.g exchanging *y* and *z* axes) messes with the the direction of the Curl of your vector field; well, it messes with the vector field itself...

Comment: Already thank you for willing to help me. 
1)I'm currently trying to use p = patch(isosurface(...)) in order to extract the Y and Z data from this object. When I try to switch these data (with set and get- commands) I get strange results and I don't know if it's correct. Should I work with the faces and vertices as stated in [link](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/patch_props.html)?
2) Concerning the rotor: yes I meant the Curl, excuse me for that. I was aware of the fact that messing with axis is very trick. That's why I adjusted my velocities, without succes however. Thanks in advance